# Como descobrir o negativo de uma cor em hexadecimal?

Tags: hexadecimal

Gostaria de saber qual é o cálculo que posso utilizar em linguagem como `javascript`, `php` ou `python` para descobrir o negativo de uma `cor` hexadecimal.

Exemplo: Se negativo de branco é preto, então eu pressuponho:

```
`#FFFFFF => #000000`
```

Ou

```
 0xFFFFFF => 0x000000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A cor inversa pode ser calculada via OU exclusivo (XOR) versus o valor máximo (#FFFFFF).

O formato de cores em hexadecimal já é uma dica de como realizar esta operação: cada um dos duplos octetos em `#RRGGBB` representa uma cor primária, cuja intensidade pode variar de #00 a #FF (255 em decimal).

Em outras palavras, cada cor primária é representada por 8 bits.

Para inverter uma cor, inverta os bits:

```
Cor     Valor HEX valor BIN                     BIN invertido                 HEX invertido
Preto   #000000   B00000000 00000000 00000000   B11111111 11111111 11111111   #FFFFFF    
Branco  #FFFFFF   B11111111 11111111 11111111   B00000000 00000000 00000000   #000000
Azul    #0000FF   B00000000 00000000 11111111   B11111111 11111111 00000000   #FFFF00
```

Um exemplo de código em Angular/javaScript que realiza esta operação segue abaixo:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  $scope.sourceValue = 0;
  $scope.inverseColor = function(){
    var srcVal = $scope.sourceValue;
    var valNumerico = parseInt(srcVal, 16);
    var mascara = parseInt('FFFFFF', 16);
    var dest = valNumerico ^ mascara; //Operação XOR
    return dest.toString(16);
  };  
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      
      Cor: #<input type='text' ng-model='sourceValue'>
      <br />
      
      Inversa: {{ inverseColor() }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei um exemplo em `PHP`:

```
function color_inverse($color){
    $color = str_replace('#', '', $color);
    if (strlen($color) != 6){ return '000000'; }
    $rgb = '';
    for ($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
        $c = 255 - hexdec(substr($color,(2*$x),2));
        $c = ($c < 0) ? 0 : dechex($c);
        $rgb .= (strlen($c) < 2) ? '0'.$c : $c;
    }
    return '#'.$rgb;
}
```

Testando:

```
// preto -> branco
print color_inverse('#000000'); 
// --> retorna #ffffff
```

Créditos: [Link](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/color-inverse.htm)

Comment: Realmente, foi o que um amigo me disse: você tem que usar o valor em RGB pra fazer isso :|

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas para exibição você pode resolver isso no CSS

```
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
filter: invert(100%);
```

Via Javascript tem a solução nessa outra pergunta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-colour